# Additional Script in shopify Checkout thank you page

Tags: shopify, setcookie, shopify-app, shopify-api

I am building a shopify app and I am unable to figure out how can I add additonal script shown in image to track orders in shopify checkout. I want to do with shopify python api. Please help! here is the script image that I want to add https://i.imgur.com/FYYDTea.png

Comment: Hey! Did you find an answer to this?